# How to reload Tableview data from another method

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Does anyone has any idea how to structure my code around that I could access the tableview variable and reload the data from `changevalues` method. Or gives me some tips how to do it, because I have run out of ideas and I don't even know what to google anymore. Thanks

I made a code sample that shows my situation. My issue: I want to reload tableview data in `changevalues` method. I have initialised tableview and segmentedControl button in CustomView init() method. The purpose of loading the data in `changevalues` is because when user selects specific segment the tableview should refresh with new data.

Main struggle is how to access the tableview from `changevalues` method?

Both UITableView and UISegmentedControl are subviews of CustomView

if my question is duplicate, please refer to that question, because I have searched for the answer to my problem, but with any luck.

```
class CustomView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var changingTableviewData = []

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        var tableView = UITableView(blah...)
        tableview.background...
        tableview.registercell...
        tableview.delegate..

        var customSegmentedB = UISegmentedcontrol(blah)
        customSegmentedB.frame...
        customsegmentedB.addTarget(self, action: "changevalues:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    }


    func changevalues(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 1:
            // I want to reload tableview Data
        case 2:
            // Also reload data
        default:
            // Also reload data
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var changingTableviewData = []
var tableView: UITableView?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    tableView = UITableView(blah...)
    tableview.background...
    tableview.registercell...
    tableview.delegate..

    var customSegmentedB = UISegmentedcontrol(blah)
    customSegmentedB.frame...
    customsegmentedB.addTarget(self, action: "changevalues:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

}


func changevalues(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    tableView?.reloadData()
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I did not come up with that :)